# How to include docs directory in python distribution

Tags: python, setup.py

I have a python project with the following structure:

```
Clustering  (project name)
  clustering  (package)
    clustering.py and other modules
    tests  (sub-package)
      test_clustering.py and other such files
  docs/
  bin/
```

I would like to include the docs directory in my distribution, but I can not seem to do that. Any pointers about how this can be done would be very helpful.

My current setup.py looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='Clustering',
      version='1.0',
      description='desc',
      author='A',
      author_email='me@somemail.com',
      packages=['clustering', 'clustering.tests'],
      requires=['numpy', 'scipy'],
      scripts=['bin/predict', 'bin/verify']
     )
```

I tried using the package_data option but haven't been successful in including the docs directory in the distribution. Is there some other conventional way of including your docs in the distribution?

Comment: See [Adding Non-Code Files](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html) in the packaging docs.

Comment: What is the purpose of including the docs in the source distribution?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You'll need to create a MANIFEST.in file and include some simple instructions on what extra files you want to include (See [MANIFEST.in Template](http://docs.python.org/distutils/sourcedist.html#the-manifest-in-template))

Example (to include docs dir and all files directly underneath):

```
include docs/*
```

or, to include all files in the doc dir (recursively):

```
recursive-include docs *
```

Comment: `graft docs` should work as well as `recursive-include docs *`, right? Is there a difference?

Comment: Need to add include_package_data=True in your setup.py

Comment: Would this retain the full subdirectory tree structure of `docs/` and also reflect that same structure in the installed package?